# Intersect between two columns returns character(0) - R

Tags: r

I would like to return the rowwise intersect between two columns in an R dataframe.

Minimal Example:

```
df <- data.frame(fruits1=character(0), fruits2=character(0))
df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c("apple, banana, orange", "avocado, raspberry, lemon, banana")
df$common_fruits <- Map(intersect, df$fruits1, df$fruits2)
```

Returns:

```
> df
                fruits1                           fruits2 common_fruits
1 apple, banana, orange avocado, raspberry, lemon, banana
```

desired output in column common_fruits:

"banana"

However character(0) is returned. Can you help me?

BR
Lukas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
df <- data.frame(fruits1=character(0), fruits2=character(0))
df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c("apple, banana, orange", "avocado, raspberry, lemon, banana")

df$common_fruits <- Map(intersect, strsplit(df$fruits1,", "), strsplit(df$fruits2, ", "))

df$common_fruits
#> $`apple, banana, orange`
#> [1] "banana"
```

**EDIT**

For a more general solution:

```r
df <- data.frame(fruits1=character(0), fruits2=character(0))
df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c("apple, banana, orange", "avocado, raspberry, lemon, banana")
df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c("apple, orange, avocado", "avocado, raspberry, lemon, orange")

df$common_fruits <- 
  Map(intersect, strsplit(df$fruits1,", "), strsplit(df$fruits2, ", ")) |> 
  sapply(paste, collapse = ", ")

df$common_fruits
#> [1] "banana"          "orange, avocado"
```